# Anyone tried having Ruby installed both from RVM and deb at the same time in Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu, rvm

Currently one of the machines on which I'm running has Ruby 1.8.7 installed as a .deb and Rails installed following this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails

I've developed several Rails apps with this machine, and from time to time I have to make little improvements to them. Until now to test the changes using just entering the directory and typing `Rails s` or `Ruby script/server` was fine.

Now the problem:

This machine is going to be inherited by someone else, probably with very little knowledge about Rails, so I want to keep everything as simple as possible. But, while this happens, I also want to keep trying the latest versions, and for that I would need to use RVM.

So the question is:
If I keep everything as it is, and now I install RVM along with my needed Ruby versions and gems. Will everything keep working the same as now? Or might I find some nasty surprises?

Maybe there is another solution for this issue. Those are also very welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't activate [RVM](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) by calling it in your `.bash_profile` or similar RVM won't do anything, so, yes, you can have it next to the system Ruby without problems.

Just configure your `.bash_profile` to load RVM or call the init yourself.

You could have a look at [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/) too.

Comment: what rvm does is adding the selected ruby version/gems to the corresponding PATH shell variables basically.